# How to send props using render in reachrouterdomv6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning from udemy but that course is from v5.I dont know what is equivalent to render and how to send props with it ? Also, in bottom of the code if element is undefined it should go to "NotFound" but its not working too.

```
<Routes>
    <Route
        exact
        path="/home"
        render={(props) => (
           <ProductList
               {...props}
               products={this.state.products}
               currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory}
               info={productInfo}
               addToCart={this.addToCart}
            />
              )}
            ></Route>
     <Route exact path="/cart" element={<CartList />} />
    <Route element={<NotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<ProductList
            {...this.props}
            products={this.state.products}
            currentCategory={this.state.currentCategory}
            info={productInfo}
            addToCart={this.addToCart}
          />}></Route>
            <Route exact path="/cart" element={<CartList />} />
            <Route path="*"element={<NotFound />} />
          </Routes>
```

I solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need to mark as resolved with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

In the v6 you can pass props directly to the element. No need to use render anymore

```
<Route exact path="/cart" element={<CartList {...props} />} />
```

Comment: I need to send things to productlist how to do it then ?

Comment: @BoraKaraduman really? <Route exact path="/home" element={< ProductList {...props} />} />